# Multithreading in applet

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I was wondering how I would use multiple threads in an applet at the same time.  I'm creating a game like Space Invaders and I wrote all the code for the enemies to move and shoot but I can't add the player in to move around using the keyboard at the same time as the enemies.  So I was thinking I needed to have 2 different threads running. I would upload the code but there is a lot of different classes and code.

If someone could help me out quick I would appreciate it a lot.

Yes they are independant of each other i got my single thread that moves the enemies in the run() method that i overloaded and all my movements are in the paint method.

should they be somewhere else?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with one thread, or with two.

Either way you have to work with the GUI Event Thread to do all the screen updates.

There is a lot of reference on the web discussing how to do this.  If you google `java space invaders` you get 1.5 million hits and usually the first page of such a search has more than what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the enemies are independent and have particular movements, if that's the case, you will need several threads enemy, and for each player, but taking into account the resources of the computer you should deal with a manager thread or task managers.

These are links that maybe help you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: How does this answer the question?